# get email when someone hits facebook likebutton on website

Tags: facebook-like

is it possible for me to receive an email when someone hits a likebutton on my website?

I have been looking into this and I can only assume it has to be possible with the edge.create option but for the life of me, I have no idea how to set this up to trigger an email being sent.

any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

You need to subscribe to the click event of the like button.

You can do this via the FB.Event.subscribe function.

Here is some code for a working sample:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script>
      FB.init({status:true,cookie:true,xfbml:true});
      FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget)
      {
         //insert your code to send email here
         alert('someone just clicked the like button');
      });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <fb:like href="http://www.example.com/" show_faces="false" width="450" font="verdana"></fb:like> 
</body>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hehe, thanks, but it's exactly the "//insert your code to send email here" that I don't know how to do ;)

Comment: oh ok, got ya. This is a little more complex I'm afraid. You could e.g. create a webservice and call it from the javascript function. Unfortunately you can't send an automated email via javascript without displaying an email form to the user. This link might be useful for you: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/CallWebServiceFromHtml.aspx)